# Issues locating data in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't find where **contact_content** is defined. I'm new to wordpress in general. So I was given this project to update the wordpress site and I've located the file that inserts the top navigation bar but where the hell is the data defined? I managed to export the database and found the data I was looking for in the theme, so I thought these were on the database so I search for the actual data, contact_content, contact_, etc. and came out empty. I've tried everything I could think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'presscore_top_bar_contacts_list' ) ) :

/**
 * Get contact information for top bar.
 *
 * @since presscore 0.1
 */
function presscore_top_bar_contacts_list(){
    $contact_fields = array(
        'address',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'skype',
        'clock',
        'info'
    );

    foreach ( $contact_fields as $contact_id ) {
        $contact_content = of_get_option( 'top_bar-contact_' . $contact_id );
        if ( $contact_content ) :
            ?>
            <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $contact_id ); ?>"> 
                       <?php echo $contact_content; ?>
           </li>
            <?php 
        endif;
    }
}

endif; // presscore_top_bar_contacts_list
```

Answer (score 0):

It is calling the function `of_get_option`, which seems to be a custom function from a theme/plugin and non-core so there is no way to see what it does other than search in the theme/plugin for that function. But if i were to guess it is probably fetching the data from the `options` table in the database based on `'top_bar-contact_' . $contact_id`

You can search for something that starts with `top_bar-contact_` in the DB.

The data in the database should follow that logic.